# What initializer does 'uniform' use?

Tags: keras

Keras offers a variety of [initializers](https://keras.io/initializers/) for weights and biases. Which one does `'uniform'` use?

I would think it would be [RandomUniform](https://keras.io/initializers/#randomuniform), but this is not confirmed in the documentation, and I reached a dead-end in the source-code: the key 'uniform' is used as a global variable within the module, and [I cannot find where the variable `uniform` is set](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/search?p=3&q=uniform%20repo%3Ayoderj%2Fkeras&type=Code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other way to confirm this is to look at the [initializers source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/895dba6c92ad4fd9bc98975b0ae23ee6230a8b38/keras/initializers.py#L434):

> ```
> # Compatibility aliases
>
> zero = zeros = Zeros
> one = ones = Ones
> constant = Constant
> uniform = random_uniform = RandomUniform
> normal = random_normal = RandomNormal
> truncated_normal = TruncatedNormal
> identity = Identity
> orthogonal = Orthogonal
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for `'uniform'` instead of `uniform =`

Answer (score 1):

I think [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289975/what-initializer-does-uniform-use/51289976#51289976)'s answer is better, though.

**Simpler solution**:

From the interactive prompt,

```
import keras
keras.initializers.normal
# Out[3]: keras.initializers.RandomNormal

keras.initializers.uniform
# Out[4]: keras.initializers.RandomUniform
```

**Original post**:

Running the debugger to the [deserialize method in initializers.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b3cb261b22a73d195a527592b49ca57e8c9ac9f5/keras/initializers.py#L487)
and examining

```
globals()['uniform']
```

Shows that the value is indeed

```
<class 'keras.initializers.RandomUniform'>
```

Similarly, `'normal'` is shown in the debugger to be `<class 'keras.initializers.RandomNormal'>`.

[Note that uniform often works better than normal, and the theoretical advantages of one over the other is not clear](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13061/when-to-use-he-or-glorot-normal-initialization-over-uniform-init-and-what-are).